# IF block in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

Can we have a block of keywords to be executed within a IF part and optionally with ELSE/ELSE IF part ?. It can be like something below:

```
Run keyword If  ${x} == "Simple"
    Keyword1 [arg1] [arg2]
    Keyword2 [arg3]
    Keyword3 [arg4] [arg5]
ELSE
    Keyword4 [arg6]
END IF
```

Answer (score 5):

Run Keyword If doesn't support calling multiple keywords, but you can run the keyword [Run Keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keywords) which will let you run multiple keywords.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
| Example of running multiple keywords with "Run keyword if" and "Run keywords"
| | ${x}= | Set variable | Simple
| | Run keyword if | "${x}" == "Simple" | Run keywords
| | ... | log to console | this is keyword one 
| | ... | AND | log to console | this is keyword two
| | ... | ELSE
| | ... | log to console | this is keyword three
```

Of course, you can always just create additional keywords:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Handle the simple case
| | log to console | this is keyword one
| | log to console | this is keyword two

| Handle the complex case
| | log to console | this is keyword three

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of using separate keywords for "Run keyword if"
| | ${x}= | Set variable | Simple
| | Run keyword if | "${x}" == "Simple"
| | ... | Handle the simple case
| | ... | ELSE
| | ... | Handle the complex case
```

Comment: We cannot have Assignment statement in the block, right?

Comment: @malhar: correct. Though, you can use [set test variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable)

Answer (score 0):

Run keyword If  ${x} == "Simple"  Run Keywords

```
Keyword1 [arg1] [arg2]

AND

Run Keyword  Keyword2 [arg3]

AND

Run Keyword  Keyword3 [arg4] [arg5]
```

ELSE

```
Keyword4 [arg6]
```

END IF

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.